# which type of ip address is suitable for wifi based socket program

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, ip-address

i'm currently building an app on android using TPC/IP socket connection. I'm getting ip address about wifi connection through using following codes:

This bit of code will allow me to get serverIp and just Ip

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(c.WIFI_SERVICE);
DhcpInfo info = manager.getDhcpInfo();
WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
```

I'm getting server ip using:

```
info.serverAddress
```

And just ip address using:

```
info.ipAddress
```

(Note: i'm sorry i cannot show u my logcat results cause they my ip addresses =( ...)
Basically these codes will get me server address and ip address of the wifi. But which one should i use for making TCP/IP connection program? the program will be based only on wifi.

Comment: The server *waits* for connections, the client(s) *open* connections to the waiting server.

Comment: what does your program do?  Do you really need to know the IP address of your phone, or of your DHCP server?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to make an app one like skype that ppl from many different network can access and be connected

Comment: But i'm not sure which one is suitable for this kind of application

Comment: Thanks for reply Lukas, i know how socket works and ppl will receive ip address through mysql. my app does not have a central processing server except for the webserver

Comment: You seem to be missing the fundamentals of socket programming. http://www.ece.ncsu.edu/wireless/MadeInWALAN/AndroidTutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like

```
            Socket s = new Socket("www.server.com", 80);
```

to connect your client application to your server.
Everything else is other's component responsibility, not you app's.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are **sure about that the Server part of the application is running on the Server Ip obtained by you, then create a socket to that port, Its better if you have a domain name associated with the Server**, if its a public server, i am sure it will have some domain name associated with it..

**Eg:**

**To Connect to the Server at port 4444, with Connection timeout of 2 sec:**

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("117.10.10.10.",4444),2000);
```

**To Read from the Server:**

```
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = BufferedReader(isr);

    String s = null;

    while ((s=br.readLine())!=null)

        {

              System.out.println(s);

         }
```

**To Write to the Server:**

```
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
pw.println("hello");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply :). I think i didn't deliver my question clearly enough to u guys.. im sorry. But I thank u so much for spending ur time on giving me tips

Comment: Thank you for saying it so politely that my reply didnt answered you question..and i thank you for appreciating the time i spent in answering the question. Thank you...